# ios7: transitioning to/from LoginViewController to other ViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, ios7, authentication, storyboard, viewcontroller

I am a newbie to ios-development. I have the following scenario with 3 Vc's. Please find a screenshot here : [image: scenario]
VC1 is connected to LoginVC. On clicking on a button in VC1 , I go to LoginVC and return back to VC1 on successful login  otherwise an alert box is displayed. There is also a "cancel" option on LoginVC . If the user decides not to login , he may click the cancel button.

There is a button in VC2 , clicking on which I would want to go to VC3 ultimately. However before I can go to VC3 I would like to see if the user is already logged in . 
If the user is already logged in , then I go to VC3
else , I want to go to LoginVC and on successful Login I want to go to VC3 . On hitting "cancel" , I want to return back to VC2. Once in VC3 , i always have to go back to VC2  after clicking a "back" button.

My question is :
*Cancel Scenario *:
I can go to LoginVC from VC1 or VC2 .How do i distinguish the source VC when I am in LoginVC?
Based of my source VC , I may have to go to VC1(source : VC1) or VC2(source: VC2). How can i do this?
*Successful Login*:
If source is VC1, on successful login I to go VC1
If source is VC2 , on successful login I go to VC3 and eventually to VC2 after clicking on a back button.
How may I do this?

I have tried using modal-segues to transition between VC's and the code below in LoginVC to distinguish between source VC's:

```
if ([self.presentingViewController isMemberOfClass:[VC1 class]])
```

But this din't work. How can we handle this situation?  Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Try "isKindOfClass" rather than "isMemberOfClass" or see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do in situations like this is make a public property that signifies my source (I mean the controller i'm coming from).

So in LoginVC.h interface declaration add,

```
// I assumed LoginVC subclasses UIViewController
@interface LoginVC : UIViewController 

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *sourceController;

@end
```

Then in VC1 implement the prepareForSegue method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
     if([segue.identifier isEqualToString@"<TheSegueIdentifierYouSetInStoryboard>"]){
          UIViewController *loginVC = [segue destinationController];
          loginVC.sourceController = @"VC1";
     }
}
```

Now in login vc you can always say

```
if([sourceController isEqualToString@"VC1"]){
    // do your thing
}
else{
    // do your other thing
}
```

Feel free to ask me to explain further if you need

Comment: ThankYou , I understand the approach , I will try this now :) I have another question now related to dismissviewcontroller .Do i post it as another question or can I edit my question here?

Comment: Put it in a different question :)

Comment: Hey User3002572, @Pillbox, could you please take a look at the second question I posted : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845118/dismissviewcontrolers-when-multiple-viewcontrollers-segues-are-present. Greatly appreciate your help :) ThankYou very much

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work. But here is an alternative which also works:

As you're using a navigation controller, you can check the previous controllers. They are stacked up by UINavigationController.

To do this get an array of the previous viewControllers as so:

```
NSArray * previousControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
```

Then iterate through them to see the type of class of the last view controller.

```
UIViewController * last = previousControllers[previousControllers.count -1];

if([last isKindOfClass:[VC1 class]]){
//Got it
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Phillbox , As I am using modal segues and not push segues for VC2 and VC3 I am skeptical if I can get a stack of previousViewControllers .

Comment: Any reason you're using modal segues over push segues?

Comment: the "parent" view doesn't really relate as far as data is concerned to the "child" view (LoginVC),so I am using a modal segue